# Building gstreamer from source in windows using cerbero .... issues with building gst-libav-1.0

Tags: windows, mingw, gstreamer, libav, nvenc

I am first time compiling gstreamer from source code and I am facing 
difficulty in building gst-libav-1.0 in windows.

I followed link given in the gstreamer website. only creation of 
.cerbero.cbc is avoided (as it gives lots more problems ,but default will 
work it say in site) 
[compiling gstreamer from source code-- gstreamer website](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/building-from-source-using-cerbero.html)

ISSUES

1) After running build command I am getting error of

> "*/w32pthreads.h:137:1:  error: unknown type name 'INIT_ONCE'"*    For
>   more detailed error see error.txt file 
>   C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Python.exe
>   ./cerbero-uninstalled buildone gst-libav-1.0

2) when I set the enable nvenc , cuda ...etc its showing :

> configure: WAARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-hwaccels 
>   --enable-devices --enable-nvenc --enable-omx   --enable-omx-rpi 
>   --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid   --enable-libnpp  --enable-ffmpeg

I have added above option in file "gst-libav-1.0.recipe" at below mentioned 
place

```
class Recipe(custom.GStreamer): 
    name = 'gst-libav-1.0' 
    # TODO - check license - plugin is certainly LGPLv2+, but need to check 
    #        the linked libs 
    licenses = [License.LGPLv2Plus] 
    config_sh = 'sh ./autogen.sh --noconfigure && ./configure' 
    configure_options = "--enable-lgpl --disable-examples --enable-static "
```

How can I enable this option in the build of libav ?

Note: 
I have added logs generated while building

```
"Python.exe ./cerbero-uninstalled 
buildone gst-libav-1.0 "
```

a) gst-libav-1.0-compile.log 
[gst-libav-1.0-compile.log](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/file/t378175/gst-libav-1.log)

b) error.txt 
[error.log](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/file/t378175/error.txt)

Comment: i was able to solve the above problem ... but still nvenc is not enabled in gst-plugins-bad-1.0  ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Python 2.7 to compile GStreamer - it looks like you're using Python3